# Cannot compile demo program using fork() and pipes() in C++

Tags: c++

All, the first part of my homework assignment is simply a demo program that I need to compile, and then modify. It was provided by the teacher, however I simply cannot get it to compile using g++. I will be creating a make file at the end of the assignment, but for the moment I am simply trying to test it out, and am having no luck. I've tried the most basic g++ command: g++ -o main TwoPipesTwoChildren.cpp . Can someone please help? I can't even get started on this until I can get this working.

```
// description: This program will execute "ls -ltr | grep 3376"
// by using a parent and child process

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   printf("TEST");
   int status;
   int childpid;
   char *cat_args[] = {"ls", "-ltr", NULL};
   char *grep_args[] = {"grep", "3376", NULL};

   // create one pipe to send the output of "ls" process to "grep" process
   int pipes[2];
   pipe(pipes);

   // fork the first child (to execute cat)
   if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
   {
      perror("Error creating a child process");
      exit(1);
   }

   // replace cat's stdout with write part of 1st pipe
   if (childpid == 0)
   {
      dup2(pipes[1], 1);
      printf("AFTER FORK CHILD");

      //close all pipes (very important!); end we're using was safely copied
      close(pipes[0]);
      close(pipes[1]);
      execvp(*cat_args, cat_args);
      exit(0);
   }

   else
   {
      // replace grep's stdin with read end of 1st pipe
      dup2(pipes[0], 0);
      close(pipes[0]);
      close(pipes[1]);
      execvp(*grep_args, grep_args);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: The code compiles for me. There are some compilation warnings, due to non-const char literals, but gcc compiles this without any issues.

Comment: @Brian Jay: Care to tell us anything about compilation errors beyond "I'm having no luck"?

Comment: This looks like C code. C and C++ are different languages. As you compile as C++ , I removed the C tag. If you intend to compile as C, use a C compiler!

Comment: You must include the error messages or we can't help.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just got it to compile, however I get the warnings: 'deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' four times. I put the printf at the top to print 'test' simply so I could tell that something was happening, but if I execute the main file, I simply get returned back to the prompt. Is anything printing when you execute?

Comment: The warnings are because the code is written in C, but you're compiling it with a C++ compiler, and they have differences in the way they deal with string literals.

Comment: Try changing the printf to `printf("TEST\n");` so there's a newline printed after the message. You're probably not noticing that your prompt has `TEST` at the beginning of it.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, your idea worked!

Comment: What is `3376`? If there's nothing in the `ls` output that matches that, you won't see anything.

Comment: Also put a newline into `AFTER FORK CHILD`.

Comment: @Barmar...I was so caught up in freaking out that I didnt even realize what the grep command was set to search for. '3376' is something that is in the demo program, but yes, after you just said that I have no idea what it would find in the directory I am running it in. I really appreciate your help.